# What's the math behind css transitions on colours?

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

If I have this code:

```
.box {
    color: #3399FF /* Blue */
    transition: 10s all linear;
}

.box:hover {
    color: #FF3300 /* Red */
}
```

If I hover on the element the colour will change from Blue to Red over 10 seconds in a smooth transition.

If there was a timeline:

> 0 seconds - Blue
>
> 5 seconds - ?
>
> 10 seconds - Red

**Is there a way of calculating what the colour will be 5 seconds or any number of seconds in the transition?**

Comment: @user2864740 I'm trying to get the colour specifically. Is there a rgb or hex hash equation that's a function of time?

Comment: See BoltClock's answer for how to get it programatically. Otherwise, break down the color by hand to individual component values, apply the transformation function at the time (for linear it is `f(t) = a + (b - a) * t`, where `t = 0.5` in this case) to each component value separately, and build the color hex from the components.

Comment: @user2864740 Where `a` and `b` are rgb components, hues or a different type of colour descriptor?

Comment: `a` is the starting value, `b` is the ending value - per each R/G/B component, separately. For example the R channel goes from x33 (51) to xFF (255). Half way through this would be `f(0.5) = 51 + (255 - 51) * 0.5 = 153` or x99 -> "#99????".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is determined by none other than the [`transition-timing-function` property](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-transitions/#transition-timing-function-property), which is represented either by a cubic Bezier curve or by a predefined keyword corresponding to a predefined curve. In your example, the value of this property is `linear`, so at the 5-second interval the value will be exactly the average of the start and end values.

The spec also defines how [interpolated values](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-transitions/#interpolated-types) are calculated during transitions. This is what it says about color values:

> - **color**: interpolated via red, green, blue and alpha components (treating each as a number, see below). The interpolation is done between premultiplied colors (that is, colors for which the red, green, and blue components specified have been multiplied by the alpha).

You can obtain the precise value at any given point in time during a transition that's in progress using `window.getComputedStyle()` and the like. From the [introductory section](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-transitions/#transitions):

> The computed value of a property transitions over time from the old value to the new value. Therefore if a script queries the computed value of a property (or other data depending on it) as it is transitioning, it will see an intermediate value that represents the current animated value of the property.

Comment: Is there a way I can get the exact colour it would be in terms of rgb or hex hashes? Thanks for getComputedStyle. I suppose that's a fallback I could use in a way.

Comment: @Akshat: Maybe this will help - http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/#animatable-types

Comment: @Akshat: How do you want to "get" this color, exactly? getComputedStyle() is one way if you're doing this from a script.

Comment: I just gave it a shot it's not at easy it seems. I was looking more of a f(t) = rgb type equation. I'm trying to implement the hover but it has mid-states depending on the linearity of the input (not necessarily hover)

Comment: @Akshat: Ah, I see what you mean. I am not sure if there is any built-in functionality for that.

Comment: @BoltClock If its based on rgb is it simply the difference between the two, in terms of individual r,g,b,a components in a linear fashion, so for 5 seconds it would just be the ones half way between red and blue?

Comment: @Akshat: Yes. You'd have to calculate it differently depending on the timing function - but that's how it works for linear.